# Logic app connection error with Microsoft Teams

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I've a code which sends resource health alerts to Microsoft Teams in from Azure using Logic app. Here I'm not able to authenticate Teams into logic app.

Please check your account info and/or permissions and try again. Details: Requested API is not supported. Please check the path. More diagnostic information: x-ms-client-request-id is '91A7CF58-4784-4107-8E48-FFE2DB45DC37'.

Below is the screenshot provided of the error I'mm facing.
[image]

Comment: I could be wrong but I’m pretty sure you need an AD account attached to an organization to make that work. A hotmail/gmail account isn’t going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Look like what you are using is a guest account.

I tried using a guest account and even enabling guest to send messages, I get the same error:
[image]
[image]

I don't think the connector manages to resolve the Team organisation when you use a guest account

Once I use an account from the same Teams domain
it works:
[image]

may be a better idea to try managed identity: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-managed-service-identity?tabs=consumption

or ask your sys admin to create a service account on the same Teams Azure AD